# showkey -s doesn't display scancodes in CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, key-mapping

I'm running CentOS 6.4 on vagrant and then doing a vagrant SSH into the box. I've been trying to get backspace to work correctly for a while now (as chronicled here: [Centos Terminal Configuring Backspace and Ctrl-h Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092380/centos-terminal-configuring-backspace-and-ctrl-h-correctly))

As part of this, I'm trying to figure out what scan codes are being sent by the backspace key and are they different from the scan codes sent by Ctrl-H. For this, I'm trying to use showkey -s as specified [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) . That doesn't seem to be working though. Here's what I see on the console, when I execute it as root.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo showkey -s
kb mode was UNICODE
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
sadfdsdfs[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sadfdsdfs
```

As you can see, showkey seems to be just echoing what I type in, instead of giving me the scancodes. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Note that if `showkey` doesn't work because you aren't at the console, then `showkey` (and `loadkeys` and `dumpkeys`) are the wrong tools anyway. They are for configuring the keyboard *directly attached* (USB, PS/2, etc.) to the machine you run `showkey` on. ssh doesn't transmit scancodes or keycodes, it transmits characters. If your only problems are over ssh, might just need to make an `stty` adjustment. A *complete* description of your setup and the symptoms you're trying to fix would make it easier to help. What you've tried so far has been so wrong it's not a useful basis for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `showkey` simply opens the first special device which it tests (from a hardcoded list) that happens to be a terminal.  Here's the list it uses (quoted from [version 1.15](http://kbd-project.org/download/)):

```
static char *conspath[] = {
        "/proc/self/fd/0",
        "/dev/tty",
        "/dev/tty0",
        "/dev/vc/0",
        "/dev/systty",
        "/dev/console",
        NULL
};
```

When you connect via ssh, the first two are pseudo-terminals, do not pass a followup test that attempts to determine if they are really virtual consoles.  But the first is the terminal associated with your shell.  By opening a different terminal, you get the unexpected echoing, etc.

When you run `showkey -s`, it modifies the terminal I/O mode using the file descriptor which it obtains by opening the device (which is, by the way **3**, different from standard input **0**). It does the equivalent for *that* terminal of

```
stty -icanon -echo -isig
```

`showkey` modifies a terminal (**3**) that you (probably) are not typing into and displays the result on your terminal.  The original standard input for `showkey` is still using the original input mode; the updated input mode is applied to the other terminal.

The behavior isn't a bug in `showkey`, because it can only get scan codes from the virtual console.  If you're not going to type into `tty0`, you're not going to get the result you expect.  It *could* be nicer, by telling you more clearly that you aren't going to get useful results.

Answer (score 0):

Try instructing Vagrant to force the allocation of a TTY.

```
$ vagrant ssh -- -ttt ...
```

I found this as a comment to this ServerFault Q&A titled: [Interactive commands with vagrant ssh. Backspace does not erase character](https://serverfault.com/questions/577078/interactive-commands-with-vagrant-ssh-backspace-does-not-erase-character).

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't help. Backspace and Ctrl-H still do the same thing and showkey -s continues to not show scan codes.